# BridgeStack — .NET client library with full 2.0 support

Tags: library, api-v2, c#, .net

[image: BridgeStack]

## BridgeStack

This is a [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) API v2.0 consumer library written under `C#`. It is heavily documented and designed to make it as easy as possible to interact with the API.

### Example Usage

To get the name of each silver badge you've been awarded on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com):

```
var client = new StackClientFactory().Create(_appKey, _token);
client.Default.Site = NetworkSiteEnum.StackOverflow;
var parameters = new BadgesOnUserQuery
{
    Sort = QuerySortEnum.BadgeRank,
    Min = BadgeRankEnum.Silver,
    Max = BadgeRankEnum.Silver
};
var badges = client.GetMyBadges(parameters);

foreach (var badge in badges)
{
    Console.WriteLine(badge.Name);
}
```

### Line by Line Explanation:

```
var client = new StackClientFactory().Create(_appKey, _token);
```

A `StackClient` instance is created, passing in your application's key and the user's access token.

```
client.Default.Site = NetworkSiteEnum.StackOverflow;
```

A default is set so that all requests made through this client which require a target site use [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

```
var parameters = new BadgesOnUserQuery
{
    Sort = QuerySortEnum.BadgeRank,
    Min = BadgeRankEnum.Silver,
    Max = BadgeRankEnum.Silver
};
```

A query parameter object is created, using the `Rank` sort on badges, and setting the range to only `Silver` badges.

```
var badges = client.GetMyBadges(parameters);
```

The API is accessed, and the user badges are received from [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com).

```
foreach (var badge in badges)
{
    Console.WriteLine(badge.Name);
}
```

The badges are then iterated, and their names are output to the console. Note that `badges`, while an `IEnumerable<T>`, contains valuable data other than the actual list items, like paging info, the actual response, exceptions that might have been thrown (and be the reason the enumeration is empty), etc.

### About

You can read the **wiki documentation on GitHub** [here](https://github.com/bevacqua/BridgeStack/wiki).

I created *BridgeStack* as a way to give back to the [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) community, which has helped me out and taught me on countless ocassions.

At all times I attempted to mantain the same philosophy in writting this library. I documented every method, reused as much code as possibly, mirrored the API as heavily as possible, and generally designed it with wrapping away complexity in mind.
I would appreciate if you let me know what you think of it. I'm sure there's a lot of room for improvement.

Another goal in *BridgeStack* is to keep the code as clean and it's public facing interfaces as simple as possible.

#### Update

I've implemented multi-threading safe response caching and request throttling, these are explained [in this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/2945/bridgestack-net-client-library-with-full-2-0-support/2983#2983).

### Download

*BridgeStack* can be downloaded following this [link](https://github.com/bevacqua/BridgeStack/zipball/master) on GitHub.

### License

I'm going with GPL

### Platform

C# .NET 4.0

### Contact

[Nicolas Bevacqua](https://github.com/bevacqua)

### Code

*BridgeStack* was written under C# .NET 4.0, though I assume it wouldn't be a problem to port it to other plaforms if enough people were interested in it. You can find the full source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/bevacqua/BridgeStack).

Answer (score 3):

## Event Logging, Caching and Throttling

I've just finished implementing these features.

Event Logging is a new feature that allows us to debug different methods on the *bridge* by hooking the events at `client.EventLog`, and examining the messages logged there.

Caching was already present on the previous version of the *bridge*, but it now supports multi-threading, and identical requests against the API are only made once even when using parallelism.

Request throttling wasn't part of the *bridge* up until now, the request throttler works similarly to other throttlers out there, providing a configurable sliding window of three seconds during which up to 30 requests can be executed, and a configurable maximum of 15 concurrent requests against the API.

You can read more about caching and throttling on *BridgeStack* on [the wiki entry at GitHub](https://github.com/bevacqua/BridgeStack/wiki/Response-Caching-and-Request-Throttling).